# Postgres performance issue during /copy

Tags: postgresql, performance, copy, postgresql-performance

I run a weekly load from csv files on one of my Postgressql tables (27 GB) using /copy command. During this time, the response time of all other tables in the database increases ( from 4-8 ms to 300 ms). Is there any way to run this load without affecting the DB performance?

Regards,

Comment: Where is this database? Is the machine it runs on managed, like RDS? Do you have root access on the server? Are the CSV files you are loading on the server's local volumes, or being piped over the network?

Comment: The database is on AWS RDS managed server. No root access to it. I spin up an EC2 instance in the same region as the RDS server, download the data from S3 to the EC2 instance and then run the /copy command from EC2 instance. This reduces the overall time of data load. But, we are seeing that the overall performance decreases. I create a new table and load the data in that table.

Comment: It seems likely that your data is loading *too fast* (and consuming too much of the available IOPS on the instance). I would try something along the lines of this answer https://superuser.com/a/239894 (PV is an amazing tool), using something vaguely like `COPY ... FROM PROGRAM 'pv --rate-limit 10m < dump.csv' (FORMAT csv);`. If you can tune this to a rate that isn't excruciatingly slow but doesn't have a strong impact on response times for other queries on the RDS instance, that may be your way to go.

Comment: Thanks Mumblestakes. I am exploring this option now. At the same time, I would like know if there are any database parameters(Memory related?)  which can be scaled up while starting the copy and scaled down to normal levels once the copy is complete. That will be an easier option(Assuming the database parameters are dynamic and don't need a server restart)

Comment: The most likely scenario is that the resource under contention is I/O; either way, you're going to be looking at the concerns discussed [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Priorities). Given the nature of RDS, your access to the tools you might want is fairly limited; I'm not sure if there's anything good available other limiting the rate of input.